# Generalized-knight's tour

Tags: recreational-mathematics, hamiltonian-path

Define an $(a,b)$-knight as a chess piece that moves $a$ squares horizontally
and $b$ squares vertically, or vice versa, in either order.
Thus a normal chess knight is a $(1,2)$-knight.

> For which $a$ and $b$, does an $(a,b)$-knight admit a (closed) [knight's tour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour)?

Assume $a \le b$, and $1 \le a,b \le 7$ for an $8 \times 8$ board.
For example, a $(7,7)$-knight can only jump between opposite corners.

Of course the question can be generalized to $n \times n$ boards.

Likely this question has been studied...? Thanks for pointers!

---

The paper JMac31 found
("Generalized knight's tours on rectangular chessboards")
directly addresses my question.
For example, for a tour to exist on an $n \times n$ board,
two necessary conditions are that
$a+b$ must be odd, and $a + b \le n$.

Comment: This article discusses $(a,b)$-knight's tours as well as various sizes boards.

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X05000880

Comment: Clearly, gcd(a,b) = 1 must hold or you can't reach the coordinates which are not multiple of the gcd. This article looks at a 3D generalization: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X10002611 . Obviously one could generalize to a (k1,k2,...,kN)-knight.